# Algorithm to match a group's preferences to a single result?

Tags: algorithm, matching, preferences

I am trying to build a small app so that my friends and I can more easily make decisions about where we want to eat. The idea is that, given a list of restaurants, each person puts down a score from 0-100 indicating how much they like that restaurant. I want to figure out a good way to combine those scores to output an ordered list of recommendations. For discussion's sake, we can assume that everyone scores restaurants normally across the scale (i.e. let's assume the individual preference scores are valid/normalized/etc.).

As of now, I was thinking of just sorting by the average score of each restaurant while enforcing a minimum score from each person so that no one is very unhappy. In other words, the goal is to maximize happiness with the constraint that no one should be extremely unhappy.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a clever algorithm or better way to achieve this? Is there any research on matching problems that could be relevant to this, or am I just over-thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

Your can first compute for each restaurant:
- the mean value
- the minimum value

Then you can easily sort by mean with any constraint you need.

Other intersting methods exist. You can for instance use minimax. It means you sort by maximum among the restaurant minimums. It guarantees that noone would hate this restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Weighted voting system, check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_voting) or other Internet resources. 
Note that this system can easily be manipulated if voters or not honnest, you probably want another system.